# Redirect querystring using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, query-string

I want to use mod_rewrite to change my old URL. For example, I want

```
http://www.example.com/lyrics?id=393
```

to be changed to

```
http://www.example.com/lyrics/393
```

I tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^lyrics\.aspx?$  http://www.example.com/lyrics/ [QSA,L]
```

but it outputs

```
http://www.example.com/lyrics/?id=393
```

Thanks,
AB

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came across the following site:
http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=16014.

After reading that, this is what finally worked for me.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^lyrics\.aspx$ /lyrics/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

So now, instead of URLs like this:

```
http://www.example.com/lyrics?id=950
```

I now have URLs that look like this:

```
http://www.example.com/lyrics/950/.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?lyrics/([0-9]+)/? /lyrics.aspx?id=$1 [L]
```

Then to redirect the old URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /lyrics\.aspx\?id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /lyrics/%2? [L,R=301]
```